# Get and click closest instance of Spectrum jQuery color picker

Tags: jquery, color-picker, spectrum

Using the jQuery spectrum color picker and I have an icon above the picker itself I want to be used to also trigger the picker.

When someone clicks on the icon, I want it to initialize the closest iteration of the spectrum plugin.

This is what I am currently using, but it doesn't open the picker.

```
$( ".color-icon" ).on( "click", function() {

  $(this).closest().spectrum("toggle");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on jQuery spectrum (https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/), it states:

`Warning: If you are calling toggle from a click handler, make sure you return false to prevent the colorpicker from immediately hiding after it is toggled.`

So that is probably what's happening to you.  Try

```
$( ".color-icon" ).on( "click", function() {
  $(this).closest().spectrum("toggle");
  return false;
});
```

Comment: no, unfortunately, didn't affect it.  But I found the part you mentioned in the docs and that should help me for sure.  I'll report back.